# Prove or disprove infimum of B equals to supremum of A

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Prove of disprove this statement:
Let A be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is nonempty and bounded above, and let

$B=\{b\in \mathbb{R} : b\space is\space an\space upper\space bound\space for\space A\}$

Then inf B= sup A

Intutively, I think this statement is true.
Here is my argument.

By Completeness Axiom, supA exists, which means the least upper bound of A exists.

Then we know that the minimum of B exists.

Moreover, we have $infB=minB$=$supA$

I wonder whether this argument is correct, or if this statement is wrong, can anyone provide a counterexample?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose $b \in B, a \in A$ then $a \le b $. Hence $\sup_{a \in A} \le b$ for all $b \in B$ and hence $\sup_{a \in A} \le \inf_{b \in B} b$.

Comment: I recommend appealing to the precise definitions of sup A and inf B in order to show they are equal.

Comment: Also I think you can prove by contradiction by assuming $\inf B<\sup A$ and $\inf B >\sup A$ respectively

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong.

By definition, the $\sup_{a \in A}$ is the smallest upper bound of $A$. Which means it's the smallest member of $B$ or $\min_{b \in B}$. Which is the biggest lower bound of $B$ or $\inf_{b \in B}$. So we have.
$$\sup_{a \in A} = \min_{b \in B} =\inf_{b \in B}$$

A simple example would be for $A = (-\infty,0)$ and $B=[0,\infty)$

clearly, if $b \in B$ then $b$ is an upper bound of $A$. And $\sup_{a \in A} = \inf_{b \in B} = 0$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).